# Rocket & drag equation?

Tags: mathematics, physics

i'm writing an assignment on firework rockets and their trajectory. Now of course im doing this with a lot of limitation as a realistic rocket calculation would be impossible to execute, at least for me.

I derived the classic rocket equation that assumes theres no gravity or aerodynamics through a simple differential equation. I then through simple calculations determined its trajectory if it was to fly straight up.

Now what i want to do is derive a new equation that includes the drag formula.

I'm a bit lost as to how I'm going to do this.
The purpose it to find the difference between the normal rocket equation and one with drag integrated into it. I've searched all over for something like this but i haven't found anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this question might be better suited for [physics.stackexchange.com](http://physics.stackexchange.com) or [space.stackexchange.com](https://space.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Alright, not sure if i can remove the question, ill be sure to post it there as well. Thanks

Comment: You should specify more detail (what kind of rocket, what kind of range, speed etc.), but in any case this is not a question for this web site.